# Bridged network connection using VMWare Workstation doesn't work

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

Environnement :

- Host OS : Windows 10
- VM software : VMWare Workstation 14 Player
- Guest OS : CentOS 7

I've being using the NAT network setting previously and it worked fine. Now I need to use the "briged" one.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Here's ifconfig result :

```
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ee21:cafd:3c40:dff8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:6e:3a:3c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1  bytes 79 (79.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 414  bytes 80340 (78.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 496  bytes 42672 (41.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 496  bytes 42672 (41.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:52:f2:7e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:52:f2:7e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

dhclient -v command gives me :

```
No DHCPOFFERS received.
```

Any idea why I can't connect? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLUTION : I had to uncheck this checkbox :
[image: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter]

Comment: I had the same problem as described in the question. Disabling all but the physical interfaces solved the problem. In the image above, I would have only checked the two Intel network adapters.